# Can the screen of apple watch simulator be copied via menu?

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

Old iphone/ipad simulator can be copied the screen with menu "Edit" >> "Copy Screen". However, the apple watch can not be copied. It still copy the iphone screen, even I clicked the Apple Watch screen first before "Copy Screen".

Can the screen of apple watch simulator be copied via menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I go to the `File` menu and click `Save Screen Shot`, the Xcode simulator saves two .png files to the desktop: one from the iPhone and one from the Apple Watch.

Shortcut: `Command-S`